# Automatically recognize the textfield on google.com

Tags: html

I'm developing a browser and I want to automatically insert a string in googles search field, when loading the page. The problem is, that it has no type="text". I've seen an approach to search for an element with name="q" (that's the name of the field), but it seems to be not very elegant, since it's possible, that the name changes over time.

Does anyone has a better idea?

THX

Comment: Do you just want to automatically search for the query? Or do you actually want to put the query in the google textfield. You can just open https://www.google.com/search?q=QUERY_GOES_HERE

Comment: No, the name won't change as it is mostly used a lot in areas public as "q" being the query parameter, you can use the link as suggested by @EthanBrouwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, when I call both "google.com" and "google.at" the text field has `type="text"`:

```
<input id="gbqfq" class="gbqfif" name="q" type="text" [...]>
```

But: Searching for an input field with `type="text"` is just as brittle as searching for an input field with `name="q"`: Google might add more input fields, rename them, do even more JavaScript magic, ...

If you just want to search for stuff, you cann use the following GET request: https://www.google.com/search?q=QUERY_GOES_HERE - This is probably a lot more stable than inserting text into text fields. (HT to Ethan Brouwer who mentioned this in a comment on your question).